# Как получить имя в модели Django?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Мне нужно, чтобы при заполнении данных, заполнялось поле с именем. К примеру:

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # логин, но хотелось бы имя
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField('Содержимое')
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

Как в строке user указывать не логин, а имя или фамилию зарегистрированного пользователя? Всем спасибо

Comment: 1. Отредактируйте отступы, чтобы было понятно, что все определения у вас относятся к одной модели. 2. Что у вас в модели User?

Comment: 1. Сделал 2. Не совсем соображаю, у меня ее нет, как ее можно создать?)

Comment: а откуда вы хотите получать имя зарегистрированного пользователя? модель с пользователями у вас есть?

Comment: От админа, который использует модель в панели администрирования, модели юзера нет

Comment: Я посмотрел в бд и там как user записывает его id. Как через id получить имя и записать его также в бд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто в шаблоне обращайтесь к `{{ user.first_name }}` или `{{ user.last_name }}`, чтобы отобразить имя или фамилию пользователя.
Таким образом можете получать и другие поля `user`, например и `{{ user.email }}`.

Если хотите изменить/разширить/дополнить стандартного User джанго, то почитайте [Расширение модели User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: То есть в модель имя не запихнуть, в бд? Например: автор - Семён

Comment: В модели User все поля - и имя, и фамилия, и email, и пароль. Важно то что вы будете/хотите отображать на своем шаблоне `html`